# azure function app error: "AI: Local storage access has resulted in an error"

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a linux function app deployed from a docker container on a premium app service plan running some python functions. One of my functions takes c.45 minutes to run as it is a bulk job. However, around 15 minutes into execution, the execution stops. I had a look in the logs in App Insights, and it always seems to stop with the following message and then has to restart the host:"AI: Local storage access has resulted in an error". This issue does not occur when I run locally.

Does anyone know what may cause this issue?

Comment: premium has maximum of 60 minutes execution time whereas the dedicated app service plan has a maximum of 30 minutes. please check if this is in a premium plan.

Comment: yep definitely premium plan

Comment: Still happening apparently: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4263 - I have the same